# Printing Entire Scrollable Flutter Widget to PDF - Need Help Resolving Issues

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I'm currently working on a Flutter app where I need to generate a PDF of the entire screen, including the scrollable content. My approach involves taking a screenshot of the widget and converting it to a PDF. However, I'm facing two main issues:

1. Printing Entire Widget: The current implementation only captures what's visible on the screen, and I need a solution to print the entire widget, even if it extends beyond the visible area due to scrolling.
2. Splitting Large Images: In case the widget's content is too large, I want to split the image into separate pages in the PDF for better readability.

it needs to work on web and pc

I've been using the following code for testing purposes:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  MyApp({super.key});

  void _printScreen() async {
    Uint8List? uint8list = await screenshotController.capture();
    Printing.layoutPdf(
      onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
        final doc = pw.Document();

        doc.addPage(
          pw.Page(
            pageFormat: format,
            build: (pw.Context context) {
              return pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(uint8list!));
            },
          ),
        );

        return doc.save();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Screenshot(
          controller: screenshotController,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    generateRandomText(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _printScreen,
        child: const Icon(Icons.print),
      ),
    );
  }

  String generateRandomText() {
    final random = Random();
    const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    return String.fromCharCodes(
      Iterable.generate(
        20,
        (_) => chars.codeUnitAt(
          random.nextInt(chars.length),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone has insights or solutions, especially for the first problem, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. If you have information on the first issue but not the second, your input is still valuable. Thank you in advance!